# How can I use Timespan til certain day/time

Tags: powershell

I have market hours defined.

```
#Define market hours
$marketopenhours = (get-date).DayOfWeek -match ('Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday') -or ((get-date).DayOfWeek -match 'Sunday' -and (get-date).hour -ge 18) -or ((get-date).DayOfWeek -match 'Friday' -and (get-date).hour -le 17)
$marketclosehours = ((get-date).DayOfWeek -match 'Friday' -and (get-date).hour -ge 17) -or (get-date).DayOfWeek -match ('Saturday') -or ((get-date).DayOfWeek -match 'Sunday' -and (get-date).hour -le 18) 
$marketbreak = (get-date).DayOfWeek -match ('Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday') -and ((get-date).hour -ge 17) -and ((get-date).hour -le 18)
```

If market is closed ($marketclosehours or $marketbreak), how can I use Timespan to find the amount of time until next $marketopen hours?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can subtract 2 datetime's and get a timespan, like `[datetime]'1/2' - [datetime]'1/1'`

Answer (score 1):

##### I believe you would be far better off calculating the DateTime of the next open and close events.

This function **should** do the job, but I may not have correctly understood your original code, or I may have made some other mistake in the function, so test it thoroughly re-write if needed.

```
function Get-NextMarketOpenAndClose {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [DateTime]$DateTime
   )
   #  For readability, and shortening of the IF statement, the following variables are defined:
   $Sunday = [DayOfWeek]::Sunday; $Saturday = [DayOfWeek]::Saturday; $Friday = [DayOfWeek]::Friday
   $OpeningHour = 18; $ClosingHour = 17
   $Date = $DateTime.Date; $Hour = $DateTime.Hour
   $DayOfWeek = $DateTime.DayOfWeek
   #  For calculations, we need a numerical version of the current day of the week.
   $DayNumber = [int]($DateTime.DayOfWeek)
   #  Is this Friday on or after closing hour, Saturday, or Sunday before the opening hour?
   if ( ($DayOfWeek -eq $Friday -and $Hour -ge $ClosingHour) -or $DayOfWeek -eq $Saturday -or ($DayOfWeek -eq $Sunday -and $Hour -lt $OpeningHour)) {
      if ($DayNumber -eq 0) { $DayNumber = 7 }
      $OpenTime = $Date.AddDays(7 - $DayNumber).AddHours($OpeningHour)  #  Opening Sunday
      $CloseTime = $Date.AddDays(12 - $DayNumber).AddHours($ClosingHour) #  Closing Friday
   }
   else {
      $OpenTime = $Date.AddDays(7 - $DayNumber).AddHours($OpeningHour)  #  Opening Sunday
      $CloseTime = $Date.AddDays(5 - $DayNumber).AddHours($ClosingHour)  #  Closing Friday
   }
   #  Return Open and Close info:
   $OpenTime
   $OpenTime - $DateTime
   $CloseTime
   $CloseTime - $DateTime
}
```

Added a function for displaying the output:

```
function ShowMarketEventInfo {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [string]$EventType,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
      [DateTime]$EventDateTime,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
      [TimeSpan]$TimeTillEvent
   )
   'The market {0} {1} days, {2} hours, and {3} minutes from now on {4:dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt}.' -f $EventType, $TimeTillEvent.Days, $TimeTillEvent.Hours, $TimeTillEvent.Minutes, $EventDateTime
}
```

To test the code, I started out by creating the variable `$Now` with the current `[DateTime]` plus a certain number of days, hours and minutes, setting it to a future date and time.

*Technically, `$Now` would actually mean now only if we didn't add the extra days, hours, and minutes, but in my mind I'm imaging if now was a certain `[DateTime]` in the future.*

```
$Now = (Get-Date).AddDays(11).AddHours(3).AddMinutes(34)
```

The following uses the above Get-NextMarketOpenAndClose function to assign values `$NextOpen`, `$UntilNextOpen`, `$NextClose`, and `$UntilNextClose`.  Having given it some thought, I realized it just made sense to have a single function calculate and return all 4 values.

```
$NextOpen, $UntilNextOpen, $NextClose, $UntilNextClose = Get-NextMarketOpenAndClose $Now
```

And finally we display the results:

```
Write-Host 'Now is:' -NoNewline
$Now
''
if ($NextOpen -lt $NextClose) {
   ShowMarketEventInfo 'opens' $NextOpen $UntilNextOpen
   ShowMarketEventInfo 'closes' $NextClose $UntilNextClose
}
else {
   ShowMarketEventInfo 'closes' $NextClose $UntilNextClose
   ShowMarketEventInfo 'opens' $NextOpen $UntilNextOpen
}
```